# How to reduce number of nonlinear terms in nonlinear equation by linear substitution?

Tags: nonlinear-optimization, nonlinear-system

Consider system of nonlinear equations:

$2a-2b-3=0$

$a-a^2-b-2ab-b^2=0$

If you replace variables this way: $x=a+b$, $y=a-b$, then this system can be simplified to $2y=3,y=x^2$. My question is following: having big multivariate system of linear and squared terms, is it possible to find linear replacement for unknowns, such that number of terms is less then in initial system?

Comment: I think you might be able to use linear algebra. Constant and linear terms are handled easily, but if you can write the square terms in the form of $x^TAx$, you can probably use known linear algebra operations.

Comment: yet not clear what and how to do it

Comment: [Here's a book on matrix operations](https://www.math.uwaterloo.ca/~hwolkowi/matrixcookbook.pdf). I also don't know what or how because you didn't give enough info on your big multivariate system. If I had to guess, the answer is some clever combination of the tools in the cookbook I linked. Good luck!